# Bad Instruction

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

When I call multisend on the following contract I keep getting "Bad Instruction" error.

What is wrong with the code?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control 
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions". 
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;


  /** 
   * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
   * account.
   */
  function Ownable() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner. 
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) {
      throw;
    }
    _;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to. 
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    if (newOwner != address(0)) {
      owner = newOwner;
    }
  }

}
contract ERC20Basic {
  uint public totalSupply = 200000;
  function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint);
  function transfer(address to, uint value);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
}




contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) constant returns (uint);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value);
  function approve(address spender, uint value);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}



contract Airdropper is Ownable {

    function multisend(address _tokenAddr, address[] dests, uint256 value)
    onlyOwner
    returns (uint256) {
        uint256 i = 0;
        while (i < dests.length) {
           ERC20(_tokenAddr).transfer(dests[i], value);
           i += 1;
        }
        return(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a guess, does `Airdropper` actually own enough tokens to accomplish its goal? (It would need `dests.length * value` to start with.)

Comment: Not about your question, but you should use a for loop instead of a while loop.

Comment: Are you deploying the ERC20 and ERC20Basic contracts with abstract functions as above, or are they implemented in your code?